# linux scheduler not able to give control to process

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, scheduler

This is on RHEL 5.x

I have run strace on one of the process that seems to be affected and noticed that the OS didnt give a chance to run for like 12-15 seconds.

The hardware is intel core2-duo-quadcore.

only 8 application processes are running and rest of them all are system processes.

any hints on why this is happening? any config I need to check to tune? This issue happens couple times a day.

All the application processes are I/O bound as receiving a lot of data on the socket.

Comment: Is the application waiting on IO? If it is, the scheduler has no reason to waste CPU time on waiting, and the process will probably wake up when it actually has some processing to do.

Comment: The process was swapped out when it was waiting for IO but then there are other threads in the application too, which need to do something like every second. In that case, I assume that the scheduler will give the process run time to execute these other threads. Also the IO wait cannot be more than 2 seconds or so as the remote server keeps posting data to my application without a large interval gap.